# How to use wildcards in systemd services?

Tags: systemd, services

I'm trying to remove all files in a specific directory using systemd at reboot.

Here is my `/lib/systemd/system/delete-at-boot.service` file (root, access 644):

```
[Unit]
Description=Remove content of test folder at boot

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/rm /home/user/test/*

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `/bin/rm /home/user/test/*` manually the deletion works fine but when I start the process, I can see my files are not deleted.

```
● delete-at-boot.service - Remove content of test folder at boot
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/delete-at-boot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-08-02 18:21:09 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 5460 ExecStart=/bin/rm /home/user/test/* (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5460 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 02 18:21:09 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Remove content of test folder at boot.
Aug 02 18:21:09 tegra-ubuntu rm[5460]: /bin/rm: cannot remove '/home/user/test/*': No such file or directory
Aug 02 18:21:09 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: delete-at-boot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 02 18:21:09 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: delete-at-boot.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 02 18:21:09 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: delete-at-boot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I believe the problem is related to the **"*"** But I'm not sure what is the best way to replace it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wildcards are not supposed to be used like that in a `systemd` service. change your `ExecStart` to:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/rm /home/user/test/*'
```

Now it should perform the action correctly.